# Python pandas accumulated nunique()

Tags: python, dataframe, unique

I have a time series dataset and I want it to be grouped by, say, month with the aggregations to be distinct/unique. However, the unique data in the second group should consider the prior group values too.

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-24', periods=35, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randint(0,15,len(rng)) }) 
df.dtypes
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df
df.groupby(['month'])['Val'].nunique()
```

The output is:
month

| month | Grouped Val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 14 |

But my desired output is:
month

| month | Grouped Val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 15 |

Because the second group should also consider the values in the first group. similarly, third group, if any, should include the first and second.

Can this be done? Thanks,

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that you want each subsequent month to only count new, distinct values (e.g. if '4' is a value for month 1, we should not count that as a unique value if it shows up again in month 2)?

Comment: So, January means everything unique in January, February means everything unique UPTO February (ie, Jan+Feb) etc. This is an example of overlapping group membership - if that is the other way to look at it.